# How to make Firefox debugger run in a separate window/tab?

Tags: debugging, firefox, browser

I do wonder if it's possible to open the Firefox's (I have 18.0.1) debugger in a new window/tab as right now the debugger's pane is too small at the bottom of the page.

[Edit]
Ok, I've made a few screenshots to show that Firefox does have a debugger on its own:

[image: Activate developer tools]

[image: Debugger appears at the bottom of the page]

[image: Clicked on debug button]

Comment: do you mean firebug's debugger ? Because I cannot think of a firefox debugger !

Comment: lol, in 2020 I use this exclusively. That that 2013!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean Firebug, these directions should be sufficient.

- Click on the Firebug launch icon so the hidden submenu appears.
- Hover over "Firebug UI Location"
- Select "Detached"

**EDIT:** 
Ok I see... you are using the Firefox built in Developer Tools and not Firebug.

So as far as I understand, there seems to be no way to run the JavaScript Debugger on a separate window for non-remote work. Here is a statement directly from the JS Debugger docs:

> The JavaScript debugger is available in two varieties: one for
>   debugging content running directly in Firefox, and another that lets
>   you debug code running on a Firefox OS device, or in Firefox on an
>   Android device. The main difference between the two is that the Remote
>   Debugger runs in its own window, while the web content debugger runs
>   in the same tab as the Web content you're debugging.

Also here is a link to the Debugger's docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Why do you think that the Debugger view is too small? If you hover over the top bar, you can drag it up/down as much as you need to. Aslo are you sure that the JavaScript Debugger is what you're trying to use? For example Firefox has other tools as well. The "More Tools" link shows other built in tools as well - all these tools together are called the "Developer Tools". Here is a link to all of their docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools

I hope this makes more sense now!

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I do know Firebug's debugger but to my surprise Firefox has one of its own....see my edit of original question

Comment: Please see my Edit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I do need 1. the debugger 2. in a new window so I can move it to a separate monitor. I was interested as not all Firefox(es) from all PCs have Firebug installed.

Answer (score 3):

Current Firefox nightlies have a little two-window icon next to the 'x' in the debugger toolbar that tears it off into a separate window, but that might not be present in 18 yet...